# How do I create a circle using hdodenhof:circleimageview (Android studio)

Tags: android-studio, layout, kotlin, geometry

I have used the library ´implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'`to Crete a circle out of an`image View`, replacing the`imageViewxml` code with this:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/iconHolder1"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/chapter1"
    android:elevation="3dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/icon1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chapter1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/chapter1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/chapter1"
    app:civ_border_width="1dp"
    app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
     />
```

But it doesn't clip away the corners. It just creates a circle around the image like this: [image]

How do I remove all the color outside of the circle border? Has anyone used this library or a similar one, or know a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I am using this library and not have probelem with it:

```
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
```

You can check documentation here [link](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that faces this issue, try setting clipToOutline to true in your kotlin/java file, that worked for me.

In this specific case:

```
iconHolder1.clipToOutline = true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
```

---

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
         android:id="@+id/profilePic"
         android:layout_width="@dimen/sdp105"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/sdp105"
         android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
         android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/sdp7"
         android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sdp10"
         ads:border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
         ads:border_width="@dimen/sdp1"/>
```

---

[image] [image]